# Can I set a breakpoint in an inline if in Visual Studio and C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Can I set a breakpoint like below (the asterisk symbolises the breakpoint dot)?

```
    var x = ifThis ?
*       This() :
        That() ;
```

Environment is C# and Visual Studio 2015.

(*I just told a colleague that I was possible but seem to stand corrected*)

Comment: Yes, but it will be on the whole statement. You can however add a break condition to it (right click on the breakpoint marker) that only triggers when `ifThis` is true. By the way, the "inline if" is usually called the _conditional_ or _ternary_ operator.

Comment: I think it never was possible to place a breakpoint within a statement. Breakpoint can be placed for the entire statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only place the breakpoint in the whole line.

However, you can:

1. Press `F11` while debugging to enter the line and see which function was hit;
2. Add a conditional breakpoint so it will only break in the specified conditional; This is the closest to what you want, and have no practical difference on setting the break point on only one part of the expression, other than the full line being marked in VS.

To add a conditional breakpoint, first set the breakpoint, then right click the red dot on the left -> "Condition..."

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio sees this as a single line and the breakpoint will show as being on all 3 lines. You cannot set it on a single line in an inline if statement.

Sorry!

Comment: But you can do it if you have multiple statement on one line (not pretty, neither a good practice but it is possible)

Comment: Visual Studio can tell the difference between the two types and treats them differently.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm just supplementing your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Karl and Andre are right. In VS 2015 you can only use the conditional Breakpoint and then step into with F11.

[image]